# How to recursively search for files with certain extensions?

Tags: linux, grep, find, ls

I need to find all the `.psd` files on my Linux system (dedicated web hosting). I tried something like this: `ls -R *.psd`, but that's not working. Suggestions?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the following find command to do that:

```
find /path/to/search -iname '*.psd'
```

`iname` does a case insensitive search.

Comment: I don't know the exact path. How do I do this recursively?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie It already does it recursively. `/path/to/search` is where you want it to start searching from. If it's the current directory use `find . -iname '*.psd'`

Comment: Or `find / -iname '*.psd'` to search the whole system.

Answer (score 6):

you also can

```
ls ./**/*.psd
```

but:

- you must have bash version 4+
- you must have `shopt -s globstar` #in your .bashrc or .profile, etc....
- will search case sensitive (or you must set `shopt -s nocaseglob` too)