# grep recursively for a specific file type on Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

Can we search a term (eg. "onblur") recursively in some folders only in specific files (html files)?

```
grep -Rin "onblur" *.html
```

This returns nothing. But,

```
grep -Rin "onblur" .
```

returns `"onblur"` search result from all available files, like in text(".txt"), .mako, .jinja etc.

Comment: man grep, search for `--include`

Comment: A great answer by @kenorb here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772340/6862601

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep, but only certain file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516937/grep-but-only-certain-file-extensions)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Consider checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985752/linux-how-to-recursively-search-for-files-with-certain-extensions).

Also this might help you: [grep certain file types recursively | commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2994/grep-certain-file-types-recursively).

The command is:

```
grep -r --include="*.[ch]" pattern .
```

And in your case it is:

```
grep -r --include="*.html" "onblur" .
```

Comment: Just so you know, link-only answers are frowned upon on SE. You will want to include a little more information from the original posts :-)

Answer (score 9):

```
grep -r --include "*.html"  onblur .
```

Got it from :
[How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)

Answer (score 4):

You might also like ag 'the silver searcher' -

```
ag --html onblur
```

it searches by regexp and is recursive in the current directory by default, and has predefined sets of extensions to search - in this case --html maps to .htm, .html, .shtml, .xhtml. Also ignores binary files, prints filenames, line numbers, and colorizes output by default.

Some options -

```
-Q --literal
          Do not parse PATTERN as a regular expression. Try to match it literally.
-S --smart-case
          Match case-sensitively if there are any uppercase letters in PATTERN, 
          case-insensitively otherwise. Enabled by default.
-t --all-text
          Search all text files. This doesn't include hidden files.
   --hidden
          Search hidden files. This option obeys ignored files.
```

For the list of supported filetypes run `ag --list-file-types`.

The only thing it seems to lack is being able to specify a filetype with an extension, in which case you need to fall back on grep with --include.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517022/6466510) instead, to a similar question: [grep, but only certain file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516937/grep-but-only-certain-file-extensions)

This worked for me. In your case just type the following:

```
grep -inr "onblur" --include \*.html ./
```

consider that

- `grep`: command
- `-r`: recursively
- `-i`: ignore-case
- `-n`: each output line is preceded by its relative line number in the file
- `--include \*.html`: escape with \ just in case you have a directory with asterisks in the filenames
- `./`: start at current directory.

Comment: Anyone who puts an asterisk in a file or directory name deserves all the problems they encounter.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to grep only from .py files by typing `grepy mystring` I added the following line to my bashrc:

```sh
alias grepy='grep -r --include="*.py"'
```

Also note that grep accepts The following:

`grep mystring *.html`
for .html search in current folder

`grep mystring */*.html`
for recursive search (excluding any file in current dir!).

`grep mystring .*/*/*.html`
for recursive search (all files in current dir and all files in subdirs)

Comment: `.*/*/*.html` glob does not work for me -- just no output.